# keras - loss: nan and accuracy is 0.000

Tags: keras

```
dataset = data.values
dataset[:, [0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]
Y = dataset[:, 1]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, stratify=Y, random_state=0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit(X_train).transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.fit(X_test).transform(X_test)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim = 9, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=50)
print('\n accuracy : {:.4f}'.format(model.evaluate(X_test_scaled, y_test)[1]))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysaqJ.jpg)

i think the problem is Scaler.. but i don't know what i do...

why the loss function has nan output, and why the accuracy is 0?

Comment: Did you check the values of X_train_scaled and y_train?

Comment: Has the same model worked well before? or is it the problem since the beginning?